# Unity Editor : How to resize and space value field of an inspector property field?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am trying to implement my first unity editor code to make a custom array property drawer with indented named entries and indented and dynamicaly resized value fields.

I am using the following simple git solution as base for my code, which allows to set the labels of an array in the inspector : [HERE](https://gist.github.com/JoaoBorks/f8a20e87dd4336bd4c3fb239f29a5c0d)

replacing the example shown in the gitHub solution, I am working with this enum as my array element name container:

```
[System.Serializable]
public enum HealthNames
{
    General,
    Head,
    Body,
    RightArm,
    LeftArm,
    Rightleg,
    leftLeg,
}
```

and sets it up on a array in a monobehaviour class :

```
[ LabeledArray( typeof( HealthNames ) ) ]
public int[] m_aHealth = new int[ Enum.GetNames( typeof( HealthNames ) ).Length ];
```

I have added `EditorGUI.indentLevel++;` and `EditorGUI.indentLevel--;` at the start and end of the try statement to indent the label of the array elements, making them stand out from the size property.

[image]

Going from there, I have searched ways to add an indent on the elements' value fields or remove it from the size property's value field. but have found no answer using EditorGUI

I also looked to be able to resize all value fields dynamicaly, but there again, no answer came using EditorGUI only. there is no way to use `EditorStyle.AnyField.WordWrap = true;` on a propertyfield. Passing the `PropertyField` to an `IntField`, using a `EditorStyles.NumberField` and setting having its wrodwrapping set to true beforehand has no effect.

I also have found a small number of `EditorGUILayout` from a few years ago, but which do not work since the solution is built from the ground with `EditorGUI`

In hope of your enlightment on the matter

Comment: @derHugo to manage the value field indentation if I follow you correctly right ?

Comment: Oh No :D sorry .. now I got what you want .. basically you want to add some value to that `rect` so e.g. something like `new Rect(rect.x + 10, rect.y, rect.width - 10, rect.height)` in the line of the property field

Comment: @derHugo indeed it works, should have been obvious ^^ and I can remove the `indentlevel++` and `indentlevel--` statements because I was trying to find a solution using these and they are not needed now as the whole line gets indented, not just the label. 

Now I just need to find a way to resize the value field dynamicaly, they really are too long taking thee whold width

Comment: That's the default behavior you'll see that any normal field behaves the same way (see e.g. [these examples](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html)) .. what do you mean exactly by dynamic resize ? How big should the be in your opinion?

Comment: @derHugo yeah the default behaviour sucks a bit to be honest if you are not fan of overly long value fields. I want to make them as small as the space the value entered takes, like, just wrapping it around what is entered dynamicaly

Comment: Ah ok .. well this can be tricky .. from memory I don't know a method to get the minimum required width of any field ... emf int and string and ScriptaleObject might behave completely different .. I mean for string and numeric value you can at least calculate it yourself e.g. doing `SOMEPIXELS * intValue.ToString().Length` .. but actually I would prefer the Unity default behavior tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the labels **and** the value fields indented.

I think it could be done like e.g.

```c#
private const int INDENT = 15;

public override void OnGUI(Rect rect, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(rect, label, property);
    var fieldsRect = new Rect(rect.x + INDENT, rect.y, rect.width - INDENT, rect.height);
    try
    {
        var path = property.propertyPath;
        int pos = int.Parse(path.Split('[').LastOrDefault().TrimEnd(']'));
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(fieldRect, property, new GUIContent(ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName(((LabeledArrayAttribute)attribute).names[pos])), true);
    }
    catch
    {
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(fieldRect, property, label, true);
    }
    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
}
```